# Java Thread issue for refreshing the frame

Tags: java, multithreading

I have written code for bouncing ball using Java thread. But I'm unable to clear it / refresh it when ball moves down.

```
import java.awt.*;

class myFrame extends Frame {
    public void paint(Graphics g) {
        try {
            for (int i = 10; i <= 400; i++) {                               
                g.drawOval(100,i+100,50,50);
                update(g);                                              
                repaint();                              
                Thread.sleep(500);              
            }
        } catch(Exception ex) {
            System.out.println(ex);
        }
    }
}

class BallTest {
    public static void main(String cp[]) {
        myFrame mf = new myFrame();
        mf.setSize(500,500);
        mf.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You shouldn't be calling `update()`. If your intent was to clear the previous ball, this works:

```
import java.awt.*;

class myFrame
extends Frame
{
    public void paint(Graphics g)
    {
        try
        {
            for(int i=10;i<=400;i++)
            {
                g.drawOval(100,i+100,50,50);
                repaint();
                Thread.sleep(500);
                Rectangle r = getBounds();
                g.clearRect(r.x, r.y, r.width, r.height);
            }
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            System.out.println(ex);
        }
    }
}

class BallTest
{
    public static void main(String cp[])
    {
        myFrame mf = new myFrame();
        mf.setSize(500,500);
        mf.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

However, you should probably setup a timer calling `repaint` instead of explicitly delaying the paint() method.

Comment: Thanks Roberto. It solved my issue. But I don't understand. Oh!!! may be it is working as a eraser... ??

Comment: Not sure what you don't understand, but let me try to explain more. In your paint(), you were calling update(). not sure what the reason was, but you can see here: http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/awt/Component.java#Component.update%28java.awt.Graphics%29 that update() implementation actually calls paint(). which means that you were going in infinite recursion (paint() calls update() which calls paint() which calls update()....). That was the reason your code was eventually throwing an exception.

Comment: Once you remove the update, the code kind of works, but every time the circle is drawn it overlaps with the previous circles. to prevent that you want to clear the frame area, which the g.clearRect call does. The argument to clearRect are the x, y, with and height representing the bounds of the component, which is what getBounds() returns. 

Let me know if something is still not clear.